# How to retrieve the last 100 documents with a MongoDB/Moped query?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am using the Ruby Mongoid gem and trying to create a query to retrieve the last 100 documents from a collection. Rather than using Mongoid, I would like to create the query using the underlying driver (Moped). The [Moped documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/moped/docs/driver.html) only mentions how to retrieve the first 100 records:

```
session[:my_collection].find.limit(100)
```

How can I retrieve the last 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically that query isn't finding the first 100, that's essentially finding 100 random documents because you haven't specified an order. If you want the first then you'd have to say explicitly [`sort`](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Query%3asort) them:

```
session[:my_collection].find.sort(:some_field => 1).limit(100)
```

and to reverse the order to find the last 100 with respect to `:some_field`:

```
session[:my_collection].find.sort(:some_field => -1).limit(100)
# -----------------------------------------------^^
```

Of course you have decide what `:some_field` is going to be so the "first" and "last" make sense for you.

If you want them sorted by `:some_field` but want to peel off the last 100 then you could reverse them in Ruby:

```
session[:my_collection].find
                       .sort(:some_field => -1)
                       .limit(100)
                       .reverse
```

or you could use use [`count`](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Query%3acount) to find out how many there are then [`skip`](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Query%3askip) to offset into the results:

```
total = session[:my_collection].find.count
session[:my_collection].find
                       .sort(:some_field => 1)
                       .skip(total - 100)
```

You'd have to check that `total >= 100` and adjust the `skip` argument if it wasn't of course. I suspect that the first solution would be faster but you should benchmark it with your data to see what reality says.

Comment: okay, good point. Let's say you sort by `:some_field` by `1` (I'm assuming that means ascending order). How do you get the last 100 while still sorting in ascending order?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, but you will need to sort collection in descending order. If you have a field id or date you would do:

**Method .sort({fieldName: 1 or -1})**

The 1  will sort ascending (oldest to newest), -1 will sort descending (newest to oldest). This will reverse entries of your collection.

```
session[:my_collection].find().sort({id:-1})  or
session[:my_collection].find().sort({date:-1})
```

If your collection contain field id (_id) that identifier have a date embedded, so you can use

```
session[:my_collection].find().sort({_id:-1})
```

In accordance with your example using .limit() the complete query will be:

```
session[:my_collection].find().sort({id:-1}).limit(100);
```